# Storing Data help, cannot be placed into TableView

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have encountered a problem of placing data into the Table View. Here is my current code. 
I am unable to load the results from the class I tried to use NSFetchedResultsController, but it won't work. Can any one see the mistake.
This is the header file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "FlickrFetcher.h"
@interface PersonList : UITableViewController {
    FlickrFetcher *fetcher;
    NSArray *nameList;
    NSArray *names;
    NSFetchedResultsController *results;
    NSArray *photos;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic)NSArray *nameList;
@property (retain, nonatomic)NSArray *names;
@property (retain, nonatomic)NSArray *photos;
@property (retain, nonatomic)NSFetchedResultsController *results;
@end
```

This is the .m file.

```
#import "PersonList.h"


@implementation PersonList
@synthesize nameList,names,results,photos;

 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
      self.title=@"Contacts";
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    fetcher = [FlickrFetcher sharedInstance];
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"FakeData" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context=[fetcher managedObjectContext];
    if([fetcher databaseExists]==YES){
        for(NSDictionary *dic in array){
            PersonList *person=(PersonList *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            [person setNameList:[dic objectForKey:@"user"]];
            [person setPhotos:[dic objectForKey:@"path"]];
            names=[fetcher fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"Person" withPredicate:nil];
            results=[fetcher fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:@"Person" withPredicate:nil];
        }       
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.names=nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [fetcher release];
    [nameList release];
    [super dealloc];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[results sections] count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"NOT REACHED HERE");
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[results sections] objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

This the method for the FlickrFetcher method

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface FlickrFetcher : NSObject {
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

// Returns the 'singleton' instance of this class
+ (id)sharedInstance;

// Checks to see if any database exists on disk
- (BOOL)databaseExists;

// Returns the NSManagedObjectContext for inserting and fetching objects into the store
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;

// Returns an array of objects already in the database for the given Entity Name and Predicate
- (NSArray *)fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:(NSString*)entityName withPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate;

// Returns an NSFetchedResultsController for a given Entity Name and Predicate
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:(NSString*)entityName withPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate;

@end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Put your call to `[super viewDidLoad]` before your code. The only time a call to super should be after your code is in the `-dealloc` method.
2. You are looping over array, getting a `NSFetchedResultsController` and doing nothing with it. You are not even keeping a reference. *This is incorrect*. You should have **ONE** `NSFetchedResultsController` per `UITableViewController`; you should retain reference to it; your `UITableViewDatasource` (which in this case is your `UITableViewController`) should be its delegate.
3. You are not calling `-performFetch:` on the `NSFetchedResultsController` so there is no data being retrieved.
4. Because you are not the delegate of the `NSFetchedResultsController` you would have no way of knowing when it got data back anyway because that is the singular way that it communicates data changes.

I would reconsider your design and review the Core Data iPhone sample projects again.

### Update

The `NSFetchedResultsController` does not fire its delegate methods until you save the `NSManagedObjectContext` so that is why you are not seeing data.

As for the error you are getting, you are trying to set a property on an object that does not respond to that property.  I would suggest loading your application into the debugger, putting a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` and see what object you are manipulating that is causing the problem.  Most likely you are getting back one object and thinking it is another.

Comment: Absolutely right - I deleted my hastily-postd misinformation. :-)